# Java - how to convert netmask to bits/length

Tags: java, netmask

If you are given a netmask (e.g. 255.255.255.0), how do you get the length/bits of that (e.g. 8) in Java?

Comment: What do you mean by length/bits?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by length/bits of it. Do you mean you want that in binary form? Because that looks like a 32-bit netmask which surprisingly enough, is always 32-bits in length.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to find out how many zero bits are at the low end of an integer, try [Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use `InetAddress.getByName()` to get an InetAddress out of it and then call `getAddress()` to get a `byte[]` that you should then be able to manipulate to get the information you want. (I'm not entirely clear on what that information is, since in no sense does 255.255.255.0 have a 'length' of 8...)

Answer (score 0):

The example given is a /24, convert each octet into an integer then use a lookup table, since the only valid values for each octet can be in the range 0-8 (ie. `0` -> `0`; `128` -> `1`; `192` -> `3`; ...). Finally, add up the values for each octet to produce the prefix length in CIDR notation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like?

```
int netmask = 255;
boolean bit7 = (netmask>>>7)&&0b1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from some of the other answers here, the question is somewhat vague because it depends on where you are obtaining your information and the netmask in your example is actually 24 bits not 8.

If you are after information about a local interface then you can use the `getNetworkPrefixLength()` method of `InterfaceAddress`.

If the information is being given to you as a String then you should break out the four octets and multiply them out in to a single `Long`, with which you can use `numberOfTrailingZeros()` from `Long` to work out the size of your netmask.